# Redux saga: take every action where error is true

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Is there a possibility to specify whether the action has its error field set to true?

```
const response = function*() {
    yield takeEvery("CLIENT_RESPONSE", handleResponse);
}
```

However, we don't know whether the action with type `CLIENT_RESPONSE` has its error field set to true or not.

I know I can check this in the `handleResponse` but that seems to be more work than it should. For instance, the `handleResponse` might get complex because for both the non-error and error case I need to write a lot of code (i.e. I want to have different handlers for both cases).

So is there a way to specify to only take that action when error is set to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Saga API [reference](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#takeeverypattern-saga-args), the pattern *(first argument)* of `takeEvery` can be  `String`, `Array` or `Function`.
You can achieve what you want by passing a function:

```
const response = function*() {
    yield takeEvery(action => (action.type === "CLIENT_RESPONSE" && !action.error), handleResponse);
}
```